# What is this panel on the doors?

Tags: locks, kia, interior

I've noticed that quite a few cars have a panel on each of the doors:

[image: panel]

I've searched through the car manual and it makes no mention of the panel. I'm assuming that it is some kind of manual door release. Is that correct, or is it something else?

The picture is from a 2010 Kia Forte, but I've seen the same thing in many other cars.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a screw behind the pop out cover, used to remove the door panel. This may not be exact match to your car, for example only.

[image]

Image thanks to Jason C.

Comment: With pics: http://www.paulstravelpictures.com/Kia-Forte-Interior-Door-Panel-Removal-Guide/